# VS Code - JSON Unicode Visualization

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get a graphical representation of a Unicode characters when using VS Code? Similar to how you will see hex colors? I see them in vs code terminal just not on file opened with VS Code. Like json files.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code automatically converts Unicode to a character. If it's not working it means there's something off with your settings.json file (in ~\AppData\Roaming\Code\User). I had this very same issue, which I solved by closing VS Code, renaming the settings-file (to settings.old.json), and restart VS Code. That fixed the visualization of Unicode chars for me (in the oh-my-posh settings file). Afterwards, it's a matter of copying-over the old settings-sections to figure out what's throwing your VS Code off.

The alternative is using plugins to switch between Unicode visualization. I found the plugin called 'Native-ASCII Converter' quite helpful, as it allows you to manually switch back and forth, or apply automatic conversion based on file-mask configuration (*.json).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dutchman,

Here is a little more clarity for those like me who need it (I can be dense sometimes so I need visuals).

- Use this VSCode Extension

[image]

- Open your `.json` file with all the Unicode stuff in it that looks like this:

[image]

- Use `ctrl + shift + P` to open the command box in VSCode and select `Convert characters: Ascii to Native`

[image]

- Then the Unicode is converted to readable glyphs like this:

[image]