# Interpret text as unicode character in VScode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, unicode, oh-my-posh

I am trying to customize a theme in Oh My Posh.
It would be nice if vscode showed me the symbols and not only the text string.

[Image showing the text that is supposed to display as a special unicode symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5czk7.png)

This is probably the same issue as this:
[VS Code - JSON Unicode Visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71874229/vs-code-json-unicode-visualization/77096479?noredirect=1#comment135912312_77096479)

First I tried to install different extentions, as I thougt I had to.
But after seeing the answer above, I understand vscode is supposed to show this without any extention.
I then tried to start vscode with --disable-extensions, and with --verbose, but no luck.

What else can I try?

I am using:
vscode 1.82.1
Windows 10
Meslo Nerd Font
The JSON file is UTF-8

Comment: you need to write an extension with a `DecoratorProvider` that inserts the unicode character as a `before` css style

Comment: According to this video it is supposed to work straight out of the boks: https://youtu.be/VT2L1SXFq9U?si=Eawh6P-900kbyeYK (See 33:35 into it). But instead of the correct symbols, I get the string like "\ue0b0"

Comment: It looks like you wrote a JSON escape for the character, whereas the person in the video wrote the literal character. If that's the case, then the premise of this question is wrong.

Comment: Yes, it looks like that, but JSON is text only, and [Scott Hansleman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6380/scott-hanselman) is actually editing the same file as I in the video, so I don't think this is the case.  The file is a theme in [Oh My Posh](https://github.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh.git).

Comment: Reinstalling vscode did not help either.  Do you all see the correct symbols in the oh-my-posh themes?